# How to use `Collections.min()` on custom collection?

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparison, min

I wrote a custom collection called `MySet<T>`, it's essentially a wrapper over `HashSet`:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MySet <T> {
    private HashSet<T> set;

    public MySet() {
        this.set = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public MySet(T[] elements) {
        this.set = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(this.set, elements);
    }
    public HashSet<T> getSet() {
        return this.set;
    }
}
```

It contains the methods that are relevant for sets like `union()`, `intersect()` etc.

I also wrote a class called `Person` which represents basic details about a person and implements `Comparable` interface:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(int id, int age, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    private boolean equals(Person p) {
        return this.age == p.age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return this.age - p.age;
    }
}
```

We compare `Person` objects based on `age` field.

I **need to write a third class** that will only have the method which will receive a `MySet<Person>` object and will determine the minimum `Person`. Of course this can be done manually by using two loops to find the minimum age but the point is to use Java methods for generics, so I though using `Collections.min()` on `MySet<Person>`:

```
public class MinimumClass<T> {
    public T minElement(MySet<T> set) {
        Collections.min(set);
    }
}
```

Which doesn't compile and gives an error: `no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that MySet<T> conforms to Collection<? extends T>` which as far as I understand means that I have to implement `Collection` interface in `MySet`.

Is there an easier way to write the method that will determine the minimum person using the fact that `Person` implements `Comparable` and `MySet` is a generic class?

Comment: Why are you avoiding having `MySet` implmenet the `Collection` interface?

Comment: @Mureinik because I'd have to implement something like 10 methods in order to use just one.

Comment: You could just delegate them all to the underlying `Set`... Regardless - is there any way to get the elements back from `MySet`? The snippet you shared doesn't show any.

Comment: @Mureinik yes I have the `getSet()`method, I edited the OP to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `HashSet` is a `Collection`, you could just call `Collections.min` on it. Note that you should limit it to `T`s that are `Comparable` in order to use `Collections.min`.

```
public class MinimumClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public T minElement(MySet<T> mySet) {
        return Collections.min(mySet.getSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile and returns the same error as in the OP.

Comment: @STaefi this still doesn't compile after adding `return` statement

Comment: @Yos: I know, I just mentioned the fault in the code.

Comment: @Yos Got caught up in the moment, my apologies. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @STaefi Got caught up in the moment, my apologies. Edited and fixed.